# How can I write in PHP a function that modifies an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments

I would like to have a function that takes an array as input and changes some values of the array (in my case the array is $_SESSION but I think it does not really maters).

How can I do that?

---

**ADDED**

It sounds trivial. But it is not. I just want to set certain values to the array. For example, I want my function to change $_SESSION['x'] and $_SESSION['y']. As far as I know, if i pass an array as an argument, then any changes of the argument will not modify the original array. For example:

```
function change_array($x) {
   $x[0] = 100;
}
$x = array(1,2,3);
change_array($x);
```

It will not change the $x.

---

**ADDED 2**

Why my question is down-voted? I think that the question is not so trivial in spite on the fact that it is short. I also think that I gave all relevant detail. As far as I realized (thanks to one answer) it is about "passing a reference". Moreover, the fact that I want to modify $_SEESION array makes it is a bit different.

Comment: Please be more specific.  What manipulations do you plan on performing upon the array?

Comment: Why do you want to pass `$_SESSION` as argument :O ?!? It's already global!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

what you mean its call : [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

its very simple like

```
function changearray(&$arr){
     $arr['x'] = 'y';
}
```

you can call this like :

```
changearray($_SESSION);
```

Comment: I think it is exactly what was asking for. Some people say that $_SESSION is a "special" array (because it is global). Does it mean that I should treat it differently (for example I should not pass it by reference. Moreover, I do not need to pass it as an argument)?

Comment: they rights its global and you dont need to pass it, but i want to learn u how to Passing by Reference in php

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is cool that you could get what I need from my very short original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The coding is like:-

```
$_SESSION['index_1'] = 'value 1';
$_SESSION['index_2'] = 'value 2';
```

If you want to change the value for the index "`index_2`" to value "`value 2 changed`", then you just simply write:-

```
$_SESSION['index_2'] = 'value 2 changed';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I would like to have a function because the sequence of calculations needed to generate a new value is big (so, I would like to put everything in a function).

Answer (score -1):

```
function change_array() {

     global $x; /*this will tell the function to work on the array 'x' out of the function itself.*/
     $x[0] = 100;

}
```