# Replacing array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I suspect the answer to this is incredibly simple and I am bracing myself for a down vote, however, having read [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/change-values-in-associative-array/4433/2) about changing values, trying to implement [array_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) and trying out the ['passing by reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597258/how-can-i-write-in-php-a-function-that-modifies-an-array) I have have not solved my simple problem.

`$levelState` is a 16 item array populated via array_push with either a string 'locked' or 'unlocked', which may print something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => unlocked [1] => unlocked [2] => locked [3] => locked [4] => locked [5] => locked [6] => locked [7] => locked [8] => locked [9] => locked [10] => locked [11] => unlocked [12] => unlocked [13] => unlocked [14] => unlocked [15] => unlocked )
```

Under certain circumstance levels below a certain level should be unlocked.

```
//Function to unlock lower levels if, manually passed. 
function unlockLowerLevels($x) {
    while($x > 0) {
        $levelState[$x] = 'unlocked';
        echo $x;
        $x--;
    }
}
unlockLowerLevels($int);
```

This function does not make any change to array elements, but does echo a countdown. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Side note, with `$x > 0` it won't set the 0 element of your array. Not sure if that's what you had in mind or not.

Comment: Cheers Don't Panic. 0 will always be unlocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `$levelState` into the function, see [PHP: Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  So either [pass it by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function unlockLowerLevels(&$array, $x) {
    while($x > 0) {
        $array[$x] = 'unlocked';
        echo $x;
        $x--;
    }
}
unlockLowerLevels($levelState, $int);
```

Or `return` the new array:

```
function unlockLowerLevels($array, $x) {
    while($x > 0) {
        $array[$x] = 'unlocked';
        echo $x;
        $x--;
    }
    return $array;
}
$levelState = unlockLowerLevels($levelState, $int);
```

Comment: 2 remarks: First it should be $x >= 0 because array start with 0 so it could be possible that also levelState[0] can be unlocked, second because all lower level should be unlooked you can include an if($arrray == 'unlocked') break; in your loop, so you can stop on the first unlocked level

Comment: First, maybe, OP didn't give enough detail I'll let them figure that out.  Second, how do we know "they should be unlocked" already?